# Object Garbage Collection Event in .NET

Tags: .net, events, object, garbage-collection

Is there any way to execute some code before some concrete class instance is garbage collected?
If yes, what is it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? (Knowing this is likely to help coming up with a better approach: intercepting the GC is not going to be a good approach.)

Comment: I would second Richard on this. Please explain what you want to achieve a bit which will help coming with better approach

Comment: I have a dictionary and it should be stored in a file before it'll be disposed. When I run my application next time, it should be restored.

Comment: Does anybody know how Ninject OnDeactivation technique works?

Comment: @Richard, @Ashwani: Disposing an object -- assuming that the OP is talking about `IDisposable` -- has *nothing* to do with the GC.

Comment: Shouldn't your dictionary be stored in a file *when your application is closing*? BTW a dictionary is not disposable, it just gets garbage-collected.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. I actually meant Garbage Collecting, not Disposing event. Corrected

Comment: Just save it when your application is closing, then.

Comment: @bsnote: finalisation might not happen at application shutdown (since non-managed resources will be cleaned up by the OS). Better to look at a name-value collection store with lazy persistence. I understand there are a number of such products (usually targeting caching for high performance web sites).

Answer (score 1):

This is the `IDisposable` pattern.  If you wish to dynamically alter the code run by `Dispose`, use a delegate, e.g.

```
sealed class DelegatedDisposable : IDisposable {
    readonly Action disposer;
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { disposer(); }
    public DelegatedDisposable(Action onDispose) { disposer = onDispose; }
}
```

A simple wrapper might suffice for you, in which you store the object to be disposed:

```
sealed class WrappedDisposable<T> : IDisposable where T : IDisposable {
    readonly Action<T> onDispose;
    readonly T wrappedDisposable;
    public WrappedDisposable(T disposable, Action<T> callOnDispose) {
        if(disposable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("disposable");
        if(callOnDispose == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("callOnDispose");
        wrappedDisposable = disposable;
        onDispose= callOnDispose;
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { 
        try{ onDispose(wrappedDisposable); } 
        finally { wrappedDisposable.Dispose(); }
    }
}
```

If you wish to execute code before an object is garbage collected, you need to implement a finalizer, which in C# looks like a private constructor with a `~` before its name.  You generally don't need to do this unless you're manually managing native resources (i.e. caused a native `malloc`  lock allocation or whatnot).

Answer (score 0):

You can use AOP in this case. [Aspect-Oriented Programming Enables Better Code Encapsulation and Reuse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301356.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you want to do before the dispose. There are many things like long running ops , ops that can throw exception etc that are not recommended.Do you want to trigger some execution OnDispose..

You can somehow do it by doing the below but again I am not sure what you want to do so I will not recommend it .

I normally have IDisposible where I am using unmanaged resources and instantiate the class in using() and do my ops there. 
After the scope of using the Dispose will be called so in the using block I cna execute my code. 
//have a destructor

```
~ MyClass() 
{
    //Do something here.
   // Cleaning up code goes here
}
```

This is translated to

```
protected override void Finalize()
{
   try
   {
      // Do something here. Dont throw exception here.
      // Cleaning up .
   }
   finally
   {
      base.Finalize();
   }
}
```

If you class implemets IDisposible you can have the extra bit of code in you Dipose

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        //Do something before resource free up.
        if (disposing) 
        {
            // free managed resources
            if (managedResource != null)
            {
                managedResource.Dispose();
                managedResource = null;
            }
        }
        // free native resources if there are any.
        if (nativeResource != IntPtr.Zero) 
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nativeResource);
            nativeResource = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in reading great article by Shawn Farkas Digging into IDisposable http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx